# Move database from file to private internal storage

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to download **huge database file** (database.db) in **zip** from server to some folder (external/internal storage), **load** it **into private database storage** of my application **and delete source file** (database.db.zip). I already have downloading and saving source file.

**Problem is** loading database to private storage. Something like "android-sqlite-asset-helper" but thislibrary have only one specific source folder from where it take database file -> "assets/databases/" but i need replace  assets by some other directory. The rest of this library work perfect in my case. Is there some way to do what i want?

1) Download database.db file with android DownloadManager
2) Move database.db file to /data/data/package_name/databases/
3) Load database

Comment: I don't understand what your question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void copyDatabase(Context c, String DATABASE_NAME) {
        String databasePath = c.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
        File f = new File(databasePath);
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        InputStream myInput = null;
        Log.d("testing", " testing db path " + databasePath);
        Log.d("testing", " testing db exist " + f.exists());

        if (f.exists()) {
            try {

                File directory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/DB_DEBUG");
                if (!directory.exists())
                    directory.mkdir();

                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory.getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/" + DATABASE_NAME);
                myInput = new FileInputStream(databasePath);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                myOutput.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (myOutput != null) {
                        myOutput.close();
                        myOutput = null;
                    }
                    if (myInput != null) {
                        myInput.close();
                        myInput = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code will export database to some folder on sd card.. its not at all what i am trying to do. I need work with database like always.. but sometimes i need to download whole file and replace old database with it.

Comment: just reverse it. he idea behind this answer is that you simply have to copy the file.

Comment: Yes, finally i did it.. problem was in checking if database is set corectly.. but i was still using sql helper from that library. Now it is work.. simple copy database is way to go